# Phonegap crash after upgrade to 2.2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, crash

I just upgraded Phonegap in my iOS app to version 2.2.0.

When I run it on my device, I get this error and the app crashes during startup:

```
2012-12-12 15:01:17.810 MyProject.de[662:907] -[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3da29530
2012-12-12 15:01:17.812 MyProject.de[662:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3da29530'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3b9152a3 0x3580497f 0x3b918e07 0x3b917531 0x3b86ef68 0xc62bb 0x1671f 0x34a6658d 0x34aa6d71 0x34aa2ae5 0x34ae41c9 0x15a03 0x34aa7ad1 0x34aa765b 0x34a9f843 0x34a47c39 0x34a476cd 0x34a4711b 0x39c2a5a3 0x39c2a1d3 0x3b8ea173 0x3b8ea117 0x3b8e8f99 0x3b85bebd 0x3b85bd49 0x34a9e47d 0x34a9b2f9 0x153f9 0x15390)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

What gives?

---

**Update:** I did some research by going through the code and removing lines step by step.

From what I can tell, the crash occurs at two places in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*:

One is here: `self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;`

And the other one is here `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

If I remove both lines, the app won't crash but it also won't load my index.html

Comment: you are using isEqualToString method to some BOOL variable..which gives the app to crash.

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas I don't have such a call in my code. Maybe the new/upgraded phonegap lib is doing such a call? Before the upgrade the app was running fine. Right after upgrading to 2.2.0 I get the error.

Comment: Lets see what others say

Comment: @SimonMcDonald Do you maybe know what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the cause for the problem. It was a wrong/deprecated value in Cordova.plist file.

To fix it, open Cordova.plist and find the entry that says "BackupWebStorage".

Change the **type** from Boolean to String and also change the **value** from "YES" to "cloud".

That fixed the issue for me.